# Fixed save as filename in PDF does not work anymore Office 2016

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I recently updated to office 2016 and now my macro that i am using to select a range in excel, and then convert this range to PDF and automatically send an email, does not fully work.

Before when i used this macro, the filename was automatically filled in the SaveAs dialog box, but now it is empty. I do not understand why.

Does anyone else has a problem like this or know how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```vb
Function Skicka_projektunderlag_PDF(Myvar As Object, FixedFilePathName As String, _
                        OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
    Dim FileFormatstr As String
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Partner_information")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Kundinformation")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Kalkyl")

    If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

        If FixedFilePathName = "" Then
            FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
            Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(ws.Range("B1").Value & " - Projektunderlag " & ws2.Range("BF104").Value & " " & ws1.Range("B3").Value _
            , FileFilter:=FileFormatstr, Title:="Create PDF")

            If Fname = False Then Exit Function

        Else
            Fname = FixedFilePathName
        End If

        If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
            If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Exit Function
        End If

        On Error Resume Next
        Myvar.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=Fname, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Skicka_projektunderlag_PDF = Fname
    End If
End Function
```

Best regards
AgatonSaxx

Answer (score 0):

The following answer isn't refined but I have also been struggling with this problem in Word 2016 [VBA to generate a default file name when Save As is selected in Word 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640262/vba-to-generate-a-default-file-name-when-save-as-is-selected-in-word-2016)
and wanted to share what I've found thus far as it is working with some success.

I was able to get the code semi-working again by adding an event handler. 
Application.DocumentBeforeSave Event 
 example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299.aspx
tied to Using Events with Application Object 
 example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821218.aspx

I moved my actual code to within the class module

```
 Cancel=true
```

had to be added to the end of the code or the Save As dialog box would open twice.
This "solution" has some drawbacks that it only works once per document.  So, if for some reason, you want to use SaveAs on the same document more than once, the name won't default.  It also seems a bit clunky/limited for my taste but it is a start.

This "solution" is Word based but you should be able to do/ find something similar for Excel.

Hope this helps put you on the path to success.  Apologies for not being a perfect answer.  Just wanted to share lessons learned as maybe it will cut down on your time to a solution!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I will be reading into your material to see if i could find something to help me with this problem. Kinda strange that it does work in office 2013 but not in 2016, and without them telling what has been changed. If you find a solution that seems better, please write back!